# Calling method of innerclass using reflection android java getting InstantiationException

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, and I am getting Instantiation exception when i invoke the newInstnace()

Can you please help

```
  Class cls = Class.forName("com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid");
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the inner class is declared `static`, you can't create an instance of the inner class without an instance of the outer class for it to belong to. Once you have one of those, then you need to use reflection to get the inner class's constructor. Note this from the documentation for `Class.getConstructor`:

> If this `Class` object represents an inner class declared in a non-static context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing instance as the first parameter.

Finally, you need to invoke the constructor's [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) method, passing it the instance of the outer class as the first argument.

With an instance of the enclosing class, you don't actually need reflection:

```
BatteryStatsImpl stats = . . .;
com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.Uid obj = stats.new Uid();
```

**EDIT** Per request, here's some sample code (with no error checking):

```
Class<?> statsClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl");
Object statsObject = statsClass.newInstance();
Class<?> uidClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid");
Constructor<?> ctor = uidClass.getConstructor(statsClass);
Object uidObject = ctor.newInstance(statsObject);
```

Note, of course, that since all this is part of the Android internals (and not part of the published API) it comes with a standard "use at your own risk" warning: The classes you are using are subject to change (or disappearance) without notice in future versions of Android.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code of the steps you have mentioned

Comment: On Line Constructor<?> ctor = uidClass.getConstructor(statsClass); exception is raised of type null

Comment: @Manish - Ah. That means that the call to `Class.forName("com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid")` returned `null`, which means that your code's `ClassLoader` cannot find the class. You might try the three-argument version of `Class.forName`, using `statsClass.getClassLoader()` for the third argument. It's also possible that the class just does not exist. This is the peril of trying to use an Android internal class in your code. It's not part of the API and the internals can change from version to version without notice. I suggest you find another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Class is there. I tried another code Class<?> localClass2 = localClassLoader.loadClass(
     "com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid");
    Method localMethod = localClass2.getMethod("getWakelockStats", new Class[0]);
    Map localMap = (Map) localMethod.invoke(
      localClass2.newInstance(),new Object[0]);    The problem here is that there is no default constructor and I need to pass parameter. But it is not working . I also tried  Constructor ctr =   localClass2.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class);
       But that is failing with NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: @Manish - The first argument to the constructor for an inner class must be the containing class. Try `localClass2.getDeclaredConstructor(statsClass, int.class);` (where `statsClass` is as in the code in my answer).